# One product with more SKUs depending on colour choices

Tags: magento-1.9, sku

Help with this one guys...

I'm using Magento 1.9.3.0 - I have one product that has two different product codes depending on panel finish (**M** - magnolia and **W** - white) but also adds two letters of colour choice to the end of the SKU that users can choose from - what I mean is this -

One product -

SKU - EE**M**55**

SKU - EE**W**55**

Colour choices - (these colour choices are added to end of SKU where * is)

Blue - BL

Green - GR

Can anyone please suggest how I would set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one configurable product with two super attributes e.g. Finish and Color

Then make simple products for each combination of Finish and Color (e.g. EEM55BL for Mangolia-Blue, EEM55GR for Mangolia-Green and so on)

Assign these simple products to configurable products.

Thanks

Comment: Hi mskhan! Thank you for your answer, it worked great! 
Just a quick question regarding your answer - I create these simple products and then I want assign them to one main configurable product, I get a list of all available products where I can choose which one to assign. 

2 products are not in the list to choose from (those 2 products have only ONE attribute e.g. finish). How would I assign them to the main configurable product please?I tried to search for it with SKU but they do not display in this list of available products to choose from.
Thank you!

Comment: Here is the video that support the answer above and shows step by step how to create the product - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J06JAyf3gs

Comment: simple products must have those attributes set on them which the configurable product is made of. If your configurable product has two super attributes Finish and Color then the products with Finish attribute only will not be available to be part of that configurable product

Comment: I understand, thank you! 
So if you had to create what I asked in the main question plus add 2 products that use ONLY Finish attribute, how would you create it and would it be even possible to create?

Comment: You can set the 'color' attribute on those 2 products

Comment: So you would create products that need Finish and Colour attribute first and then create 2 products ONLY with Colour attribute (don't create it on both finish and colour attribute!) - is that correct?

Comment: these simple products will have both finish and color attributes set. If you have simple products, already, created with finish attribute then set the value of color attribute as well on those products. e.g. Finish (Mangolia) Color (Blue)...thats one product....Finish (Mangolia) Color (White) thats another product and so on

Comment: Yes, that's right and it works perfect this way! 
However, if I wanted to create a few products like for example Finish (Mangolia) Color (Blue)...that's one product....Finish (Mangolia) Color (White) another product etc. and then one product Finish (Magnolia) Colour (none) another product Finish (White) Colour (none) - just to set it up for Finish attribute but it all has to be under one configurable product - would this be possible to create?

Comment: I don't think so it will work

Comment: Sorry did you say it is not possible to create something like this?

Comment: I think its not possible

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help! 
Can you think of any other ways how I would be able to create such a functionality please?

Comment: Hi, if you select 2 attributes to create configurable product - like "finish" and "color" then all your associated products should have both of values assigned. To create simple associated products with one option only, like you have mentioned Finish - while, Color - none, you can, as a way out create another separate configurable product with one dropdown only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a configurable product. Each variation is a simple product that has its own SKU (like "magnolia blue" = "EEM55BL") and this SKU will be used when the configured product is ordered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried that but to create configurable product, you need to add general SKU and then you can modify SKU to be whatever you like, right? My problem is that there is a lot of products that start SKU with EEM and EEW (number is different), how would I go around that?